# Nystroem Method for Kernel Approximation

Tags: scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, kernel-trick, nonlinear

I have been reading about the Nyström method for low-rank kernel aproximation. This method is implemented in scikit-learn [1] as a method to project data samples to a low-rank approximation of the kernel feature mapping.

To the best of my knowledge, given a training set $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and a kernel function, it generates a low-rank approximation of the $n \times n$ kernel matrix $K$ by applying SVD to $W$ and $C$.

$K = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} W & K_{21}^T \\ K_{21} & K_{22} \end{array} \right ]$ $C = \left [\begin{array}{cc} W \\ K_{21} \end{array}\right ]$, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times l}$

However, **I do not understand how the low-rank approximation of the Kernel matrix can be used to project new samples to the approximated kernel feature space**. The papers I have found (e.g. [2]) are not of great help, for they are little didactic.

Also, I am curious about the computational complexity of this method, both in training and test phases.

[1] http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html#nystroem-kernel-approx

[2] http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/kumar12a/kumar12a.pdf

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let's derive the Nyström approximation in a way that should make the answers to your questions clearer.

The key assumption in Nyström is that the kernel function is of rank $m$. (Really we assume that it's *approximately* of rank $m$, but for simplicity let's just pretend it's *exactly* rank $m$ for now.) That means that *any* kernel matrix is going to have rank at most $m$,
and in particular
$$
K = \begin{bmatrix}
k(x_1, x_1) & \dots & k(x_1, x_n)
\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k(x_n, x_1) & \dots & k(x_n, x_n)
\end{bmatrix}
,$$
is rank $m$.
Therefore there are $m$ nonzero eigenvalues, and we can write the eigendecomposition of $K$ (ignoring the zero eigenvalues) as
$$K = U \Lambda U^T$$
with eigenvectors stored in $U$, of shape $n \times m$,
and eigenvalues arranged in $\Lambda$, an $m \times m$ diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are all positive.

So, let's pick $m$ elements, usually uniformly at random but possibly according to other schemes – all that matters in this simplified version is that $K_{11}$ be of rank $m$. Once we do, just relabel the points so that we end up with the kernel matrix in blocks:
$$
K = \begin{bmatrix} K_{11} & K_{21}^T \\ K_{21} & K_{22} \end{bmatrix}
,$$
where we evaluate each entry in $K_{11}$ (which is $m \times m$) and $K_{21}$ ($(n-m) \times m$), but don't want to evaluate any entries in $K_{22}$.

Now, we can split up the eigendecomposition according to this block structure too:
\begin{align}
K &= U \Lambda U^T
\\&= \begin{bmatrix}U_1 \\ U_2\end{bmatrix} \Lambda \begin{bmatrix}U_1 \\ U_2\end{bmatrix}^T
\\&= \begin{bmatrix} U_1 \Lambda U_1^T & U_1 \Lambda U_2^T \\
                     U_2 \Lambda U_1^T & U_2 \Lambda U_2^T \end{bmatrix}
,\end{align}
where $U_1$ is $m \times m$ and $U_2$ is $(n-m) \times m$.
So, we have $K_{11} = U_1 \Lambda U_1^T$ (although notice that this is *not* an eigendecomposition of $K_{11}$), and $K_{21} = U_2 \Lambda U_1^T$. If $U_1$ is invertible, then $K_{11}^{-1} = U_1^{-T} \Lambda^{-1} U_1^{-1}$, and then we have
\begin{align}
K_{21} K_{11}^{-1} K_{21}^T
  &= U_2 \Lambda U_1^T U_1^{-T} \Lambda^{-1} U_1^{-1} U_1 \Lambda U_2^T
\\&= U_2 \Lambda U_2^T
\\&= K_{22}
.\end{align}
This tells us what $K_{22}$ must be under this rank assumption,
as long as $U_1$ is invertible.
$U_1$ should be almost surely invertible if $X$ is sampled from a continuous distribution; it is *possible* for it to not be invertible (consider the full $n \times n$ eigenvectors being a permuted identity such that $U_1$ has an all-zero row), but in that case you can follow [another path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_matrix_approximations#Theorem_for_kernel_approximation) that I find less intuitive to the same result.

But we don't want to actually construct $K_{22}$, because that's expensive. Instead, notice that
$$
K_{21} K_{11}^{-1} K_{21}^T = \left( K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12} \right) \left( K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12} \right)^T
.$$
We can see then that using the *feature matrix* $K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12}$, of shape $(n-m) \times m$, corresponds to these imputed kernel values. If we use $K_{11} K_{11}^{-\frac12} = K_{11}^{\frac12}$ for the points in the first partition, we have a set of $m$-dimensional features
$$
\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
K_{11}^{\frac12} \\
K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12}
\end{bmatrix}
.$$
We can just quickly verify that $\Phi$ corresponds to the correct kernel matrix:
\begin{align}
\Phi \Phi^T
&= \begin{bmatrix}
K_{11}^{\frac12} \\
K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
K_{11}^{\frac12} \\
K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\\&=\begin{bmatrix}
K_{11}^{\frac12} K_{11}^{\frac12} &
K_{11}^{\frac12} K_{11}^{-\frac12} K_{21}^T  \\
K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12} K_{11}^{\frac12} &
K_{21} K_{11}^{-\frac12} K_{11}^{-\frac12} K_{21}^T
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=\begin{bmatrix}
K_{11} &
K_{21}^T  \\
K_{21} &
K_{21} K_{11}^{-1} K_{21}^T
\end{bmatrix}
\\&= K
.\end{align}

So, all we need to do is train our regular learning model with the $m$-dimensional features $\Phi$. This will be *exactly* the same (under the assumptions we've made) as the kernelized version of the learning problem with $K$.

Now, for an individual data point $x$, the features in $\Phi$ correspond to
$$
\phi(x) = \begin{bmatrix} k(x, x_1) & \dots & k(x, x_m) \end{bmatrix} K_{11}^{-\frac12}
.$$
This vector is just the relevant row of either $K_{11}$ or $K_{21}$, so $\phi(x)$ that multiplies that row by $K_{11}^{-\frac12}$ is indeed the corresponding row of $\Phi$.

So...this is still true for a novel test point. You just do the same thing:
$$
\Phi_\text{test} = K_{\text{test},1} K_{11}^{-\frac12}
.$$
Because we assumed the kernel is rank $m$, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}K_{\text{train}} & K_{\text{train,test}} \\ K_{\text{test,train}} & K_{\text{test}} \end{bmatrix}$ is also of rank $m$, and the reconstruction of $K_\text{test}$ is still exact by exactly the same logic as for $K_{22}$.

---

Above, we assumed that the kernel matrix $K$ was *exactly* rank $m$. This is not usually going to be the case; for a Gaussian kernel, for example, $K$ is always rank $n$, but the smaller eigenvalues typically drop off pretty quickly, so it's going to be *close to* a matrix of rank $m$, and our reconstructions of $K_{21}$ or $K_{\text{test},1}$ are going to be *close to* the true values (but not exactly the same). They'll be better reconstructions the closer the eigenspace of $K_{11}$ gets to that of $K$ overall, which is why choosing the right $m$ points is important in practice.

If $K_{11}$ has any zero eigenvalues, you can replace inverses with pseudoinverses and everything still works; you just replace $K_{21}$ in the reconstruction with $K_{21} K_{11}^\dagger K_{11}$.

You can use the SVD instead of the eigendecomposition if you'd like; since $K$ is psd, they're the same thing, but the SVD *might* be a little more robust to slight numerical error in the kernel matrix, and that's what scikit-learn does. scikit-learn's [actual implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/3f89022fa04d293152f1d32fbc2a5bdaaf2df364/sklearn/kernel_approximation.py#L1065) does this, though it uses $\max(\lambda_i, 10^{-12})$ in the inverse instead of the pseudoinverse. This is related to avoiding numerical error, but I'm not sure why they make small eigenvalues $10^{12}$ instead of zero [like `np.linalg.pinv` does](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. It was of great help. However, I still do not fully understand how the computation of $K_{11}^{-1/2}$ is carried out in scikit-learn.

Can you provide some reference of how this is achieved through SVD?

Comment: When $A$ is positive semidefinite, the eigendecomposition $U \Lambda U^T$ coincides with the SVD. scikit-learn, because due to numerical error $A$ might be slightly non-psd, instead computes $U \Sigma V^T$, and uses $A^{-\frac12} = V \Sigma^{-\frac12} V^T$, so that $A$'s features become $A V \Sigma^{-\frac12} V^T = U \Sigma V^T V \Sigma^{-\frac12} V^T = U \Sigma^{\frac12} V^T = A^{\frac12}$. It's the same thing, basically.

Comment: Alright, so $K_{11}^{-1/2} = V \Sigma^{-1/2} V^T$, but the computation performed by scikit-learn is not that: 

self.normalization_ = np.dot(U * 1. / np.sqrt(S), V).

 Is normalization_ equal to $K_{11}^{1/2}$ or $K_{11}^{-1/2}$? I assume it must be $K_{11}^{-1/2}$, because the normalization_ matrix is later used to project test samples as np.dot(embedded, self.normalization_.T)

Comment: Whoops, sorry, yeah they use $U \Sigma^{-\frac12} V^T = K^{-\frac12}$. It all doesn't really matter since $U \approx V$, but since they do the transpose the features for $K_{11}$ end up as $U\Sigma V^T V \Sigma^{-\frac12} U^T = U \Sigma^{\frac12} U^T$.

Comment: Last question, I do not see how S = np.maximum(S, 1e-12), normalization_ = np.dot(U * 1. / np.sqrt(S), V) equals $U\Sigma^{-1/2} V^T$. Specifically, how is $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ computed? I dont see the -1.

Comment: Raising a diagonal matrix to a power is the same as raising each element to a power, and $x^{-\frac12} = 1 / \sqrt x$.  In numpy broadcasting notation, elementwise multiplication by a vector is the same as right-multiplying by a diagonal matrix. Also, that code uses $V$ to mean what I was calling $V^T$.

Comment: "right-multiply both sides by ..." - Why would $U_1$ be an orthogonal matrix? I get that $U$ is orthogonal, but $U_1$ is a sub-matrix of $U$.

Comment: @Newton You're absolutely right – sorry about that, that was wrong here for a long time! It's not necessary, though; I updated the answer.